# Filter Dataset to get just images from specific class

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I want to prepare the omniglot dataset for n-shot learning.
Therefore I need 5 samples from 10 classes (alphabet)

Code to reproduce

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import numpy as np

builder = tfds.builder("omniglot")
# assert builder.info.splits['train'].num_examples == 60000
builder.download_and_prepare()
# Load data from disk as tf.data.Datasets
datasets = builder.as_dataset()
dataset, test_dataset = datasets['train'], datasets['test']


def resize(example):
    image = example['image']
    image = tf.image.resize(image, [28, 28])
    image = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(image, )
    image = image / 255
    one_hot_label = np.zeros((51, 10))
    return image, one_hot_label, example['alphabet']


def stack(image, label, alphabet):
    return (image, label), label[-1]

def filter_func(image, label, alphabet):
    # get just images from alphabet in array, not just 2
    arr = np.array(2,3,4,5)
    result = tf.reshape(tf.equal(alphabet, 2 ), [])
    return result

# correct size
dataset = dataset.map(resize)
# now filter the dataset for the batch
dataset = dataset.filter(filter_func)
# infinite stream of batches (classes*samples + 1)
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(1024).batch(51)
# stack the images together
dataset = dataset.map(stack)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
dataset = dataset.batch(32)

for i, (image, label) in enumerate(tfds.as_numpy(dataset)):
    print(i, image[0].shape)
```

Now I want to filter the images in the dataset by using the filter function.
tf.equal just let me filter by one class, I want something like tensor in array.

Do you see a way doing this with the filter function?
Or is this the wrong way and there is a much simpler way?

I want to create a batch of 51 images and according labels, which are from the same N=10 classes. From every class, I need K=5 different images and an additional one (which I need to classify). Every batch of N*K+1 (51) images should be from 10 new random classes.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `Also: this filtering must be applied for every new batch (of size 51) randomly :-/` `<--` clarify this. What does it mean to apply filtering randomly?

Comment: I want to create a batch of 51 images and according labels, which are from the same 10 classes. Every batch of 51 images should be from 10 new random classes.

Comment: It is even worse: I need K (5) images per class, from N (10) random classes, and one additional image -> batch size of N*K+1 (51) images

Comment: Just went through `tf.Dataset` documentation. In my opinion, it is impossible to do with current  `tf.Dataset` API. But you can convert it to numpy, prepare this dataset in Python/numpy and then create new dataset. And you should take the 51th sample for classification from test data. It shouldn't be part of the train data batch.

Comment: Okay, too bad. Thank you very much for your time. Does the 51st sample need to be from test data?!

Comment: Also: What does it mean when it comes to copy time to GPU etc. is there any chance for the pipeline to be fast?

Comment: `does the 51st sample need to be from test data?!` - if you're going to use the 51st sample to test your model it should be from test dataset, otherwise, if you want to train with this sample it should be from train dataset. ; There is significant overhead when copying from-to GPU, or even when invoking GPU kernels (the function that executes code on GPU). `tf.Dataset` is something that tries to optimize these operations so you should feed data using from `tf.Dataset`. They are still expensive, however.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and explanation, this helped me very much! Should I tick your answer below as the answer? It doesn't fit 100% (as there is no perfect answer) but suits partially

Comment: I mean, if it helped you, yes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To KEEP only specific labels use this predicate:

```py
dataset = datasets['train']

def predicate(x, allowed_labels=tf.constant([0, 1, 2])):
    label = x['label']
    isallowed = tf.equal(allowed_labels, tf.cast(label, allowed_labels.dtype))
    reduced = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(isallowed, tf.float32))
    return tf.greater(reduced, tf.constant(0.))

dataset = dataset.filter(predicate).batch(20)

for i, x in enumerate(tfds.as_numpy(dataset)):
    print(x['label'])
# [1 0 0 1 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 2 2 0 1]
# [1 0 2 2 0 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 0 2 0 2 1 2 1 1]
# [2 1 2 1 0 1 1 0 1 2 2 0 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

`allowed_labels` specifies labels you want to keep. All labels that are not in this tensor will be filtered out.

Comment: is it possible to change the values of tf.constant with each generation of one batch? so that I could feed 10 random classes for each generated batch

Comment: Yes, sure. I’ll update my answer tomorrow, it’s past midnight at my place.

Comment: Here too, just needed to have a look on your answer :-) Thank you very much for your time and effort!

Comment: Please have a look at the last comment above and the altered text.

Comment: Hi @Vlad and janbolle, I want exactly the same feature like "change the values of tf.constant with each generation of one batch?". Did you find any solution for that? It is very appreciated if you can update the answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @FBai, Ask a question and reference me on it. I need to see the example to understand what you want: `input --> expected output`

Comment: Hi @Vlad, thank you very much for replying, please see my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/59154851/8150258