# Reducing a dataset's classes

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Let's say i have the CIFAR-100(images) dataset initialized like this:

```
cifar100_builder = tfds.builder("cifar100")
cifar100_builder.download_and_prepare()
ds_train = cifar100_builder.as_dataset(split="train")
ds_test = cifar100_builder.as_dataset(split="test")
```

the ds_train for example is an object of type:

```
<DatasetV1Adapter shapes: {coarse_label: (), image: (32, 32, 3), label: ()}, types: {coarse_label: tf.int64, image: tf.uint8, label: tf.int64}> which is a `tf.data.dataset`
```

This dataset contains 100 classes.Let's say i also have a list called `our_index` which has 20 distinct elements each representing one class.What i would like to do is iterate through the ds_train dataset and keep only the elements that belong in one of these 20 classes.To do this i think i could use this:[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter][1].

but i am not sure how.Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter Dataset to get just images from specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731774/filter-dataset-to-get-just-images-from-specific-class)

Comment: Not quite.The problem is that i can't access the ['label'] field inside the filter_fn function while i can normaly get it outside of it.

Comment: you could just access the label field just like a dictionary. I was able to filter it using the link above and posted it as the answer. You could check it out and edit it as you need. @Epitheoritis32

Answer (score 1):

Using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731774/filter-dataset-to-get-just-images-from-specific-class) the link of which I provided you with in the comment above also, I could filter the dataset to include labels 0, 1 and 2 only as follows:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

def predicate(x, allowed_labels=tf.constant([0., 1., 2.])):
    label = x['label']
    isallowed = tf.equal(allowed_labels, tf.cast(label, tf.float32))
    reduced = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(isallowed, tf.float32))
    return tf.greater(reduced, tf.constant(0.))

cifar100_builder = tfds.builder("cifar100")
cifar100_builder.download_and_prepare()
ds_train = cifar100_builder.as_dataset(split="train")
ds_test = cifar100_builder.as_dataset(split="test")

filtered_ds_train=ds_train.filter(predicate)
filtered_ds_test=ds_test.filter(predicate)
```

Now iterating and printing the labels for *filtered_ds_train*, we can see that only *3* labels are selected.

```
for x in myclasses:
  print(x['label'])
```

You could change the *allowed_labels=tf.constant([0., 1., 2.])* argument to include other class labels. Currently it selects labels 0, 1, and 2.