# numpy.where narrowing array dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use some classes from the [CIFAR-100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIFAR-10) dataset to train a model. I used NumPy `where` to filter the dataset, but it’s narrowing image arrays dimensions.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar100

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar100.load_data()
index = np.where((y_train == 1) | (y_train == 2))
print('Images Shape: {}'.format(x_train.shape))
X_train = x_train[index]
Y_train = y_train[index]
print('Images Shape: {}'.format(X_train.shape))
```

Prints:

> Images Shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
>
> Images Shape: (1000, 32, 3)

What I tried so far:

After filtering I tried to convert results to the shape of an image like this:

`index = np.asarray(index).reshape(x_train.shape[0])`

But then I get this error:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 2000 into shape (50000,)

I want to train a model using only 10 classes from the CIFAR-100 dataset.

Here is my model:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar100
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, Dense, MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3),
                 # strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 padding='same',  # 'valid',
                 input_shape=(32, 32, 3)))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                 # strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),
                 # strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train,
          Y_train,
          epochs=5,
          batch_size=64)
```

Comment: Do you mind giving more detail about what you are trying to achieve? `where` simply fetches indices of elements within the array that match the user-supplied condition.

Comment: @Patol75 Yes, I edited my post to be more specific

Comment: One tricky thing about np.where is that it returns a tuple: try setting index to np.where((y_train == 5) | (y_train == 8))[0].

Comment: @vstack17 I tried this but then when I tried to fit the model I get this error: ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 10) are incompatible

Comment: is `y_train` (50000,1) shape?  `index` is (I think) a 2 element tuple with 1000 element arrays, so with array wrapper it becomes a (2,1000) array.  Make sure you understand `index` before using it.

Comment: @hpaulj Makes sense, can you give more detail about how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that training on a subset of the `y_train` cases is the right way to go.  Usually training is done on a 'random' subset of all cases.  `keras` and such have `split` functions that split a dataset, both `X` and `y` into train and test sets.

But as follow on to my comment, to explain the behaviour that you see.

With a (n,1) `y_train`:

```
In [203]: y = np.arange(10)[:,None]
In [204]: idx = np.nonzero((y<4)|(y>7))
In [205]: idx
Out[205]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

`nonzero/where` returns a tuple of index arrays, one array per dimension.  Since the 2nd dimension is 1, `idx[1]` is all 0, and doesn't provide any useful information.

When used to index the 4d `x_train`, `idx` selects 6 values on the first dimension, and just 1, the first, on the 2nd:

```
In [206]: x = np.ones((10,2,3,4),int)
In [207]: x[idx].shape
Out[207]: (6, 3, 4)
```

Indexing with just the first array retains the 2nd dimension:

```
In [208]: x[idx[0]].shape
Out[208]: (6, 2, 3, 4)
```

I have no idea what you were trying to do with:

```
index = np.asarray(index).reshape(x_train.shape[0])
```

In my example `x.shape[0]` is 10, but `idx[0]` is (6,).  It doesn't make sense to reshape `idx[0]`, much less both arrays.

```
In [209]: np.array(idx)
Out[209]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: My goal in this answer is to explain the immediate error - with a focus on the `numpy` aspect.  I showed how the select specific cases (1st dimension) for `x_train`.  You could do the same with `Y`.  I don't think you need to "reshape" or otherwise fiddle with `index`.  Others will have to address the tensorflow aspect.

Answer (score 0):

The code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60709541/9936645) is what you need:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow as tf

def predicate(x, allowed_labels=tf.constant([0., 1., 2.])):
    label = x['label']
    isallowed = tf.equal(allowed_labels, tf.cast(label, tf.float32))
    reduced = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(isallowed, tf.float32))
    return tf.greater(reduced, tf.constant(0.))

cifar100_builder = tfds.builder("cifar100")
cifar100_builder.download_and_prepare()
ds_train = cifar100_builder.as_dataset(split="train")
ds_test = cifar100_builder.as_dataset(split="test")

filtered_ds_train=ds_train.filter(predicate)
filtered_ds_test=ds_test.filter(predicate)
```